# Stripe Create Recipient

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to transfer money from Stripe account to third party Bank Account. So from stripe docs i have to create a recipient to transfer money. Here is my code from [Sripe Api](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_recipient)

```
include('stripe/autoload.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_gKaIw7i5T24J4dxCCn3Iqsxe");

$recipient = \Stripe\Recipient::create(array(
  "name" => "John Doe",
  "type" => "individual")
); 
var_dump($recipient);
exit;
```

I am not getting any error but it is not working. Can anyone please help me to create recipient or transfer to a third party bank account from stripe.

Comment: Did you included stripe library at the top of your code ?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php, its easy to integrate.

Comment: yes i have included and is working fine for payment and refund.

Comment: In console it is showing "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"

Comment: please enable errors , you should get error if 500 internal error is there.

Comment: Recipients are deprecated and not supported

Comment: @MatthewArkin I know this is deprecated but this don't mean this will not work.

Comment: you should really consider against using deprecated and not supported functionality, especially in a production environment handling funds. The proper way would be to use Stripe connect.